# Is it possible to wrap an asynchronous event and its callback in a function that returns a boolean?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to write a simple test that creates an image element, checks the image attributes, and then returns true/false. The problem is that using the onload event makes the test asynchronous. On it own this isn't a problem (using a callback as I've done in the code below is easy), but what I can't figure out is how to encapsulate this into a single function that returns a boolean.

I've tried various combinations of closures, recursion, and self-executing functions but have had no luck.

So my question: am I being dense and overlooking something simple, or is this in fact not possible, because, no matter what, I'm still trying to wrap an asynchronous function in synchronous expectations?

**Here's the code:**

```
var supportsImage = function(callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    //Check attributes and pass true or false to callback
    callback(true);
  };
  img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=';
};

supportsImage(function(status){
  console.log(status);  
});
```

To be clear, what I want is to be able to wrap this in something such that it can be used like:

```
if (supportsImage) {
  //Do some crazy stuff
}
```

Thanks!

(Btw, I know there are a ton of SO questions regarding confusion about synchronous vs. asynchronous. Apologies if this can be reduced to something previously answered.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can pass your "crazy stuff" into `supportsImage`, e.g.

```
supportsImage(function(result){
    if(result) {
        //Do some crazy stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. "Doing the stuff" inside the callback is what I'm currently doing but I was curious to know if there was a way that would allow me to isolate the result passed to the callback. I didn't think it was possible but I wanted to ask before accepting it couldn't be done. =)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No you can't....

Comment: My short answer was so short SO wouldn't let me post it :-)

Comment: @Pointy: That is why I had to add some more dots  :D

Comment: I **have** seen a `No` answer before. The poster told me the trick is to first write a long answer and then later edit it into a short answer. It looks like stackoverflow only filter submits, not edits.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just design your code so that "Do some crazy stuff" is within your callback?
That's how callbacks are supposed to work, you're still trying to think synchronously.

```
var supportsImage = function(callback) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    //Check attributes and invoke callback if true
    callback();
  };
  img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=';
};

supportsImage(function() {
  // Do some crazy stuff  
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now. It works but what I'm interested in is not "doing the crazy stuff" (which is easy) but storing the result of the callback in a way that can be accessed synchronously... which, as I figured, isn't possible. Thanks.